# Windows NFS Share: Allow Linux uids

Tags: linux, windows, nfs, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a couple of NFS shares set up on my Windows Server 2012 box, but they only allow Linux users with uid 0 to access them (aka the root user). How and where do I specify that I, for example, want to allow a user with uid 1000 to be able to read/write to a share?

Comment: I found an alternative solution, which works well for me. By giving "Everyone" full permissions to the shared folder in Windows (in the Security tab of the folder), everyone who can mount it can r/w from/to it. By doing this, you give all of the users on a machine full permissions. Credit: http://www.vkernel.ro/blog/installing-and-configuring-nfs-on-windows-server-2012r2

Comment: I am still interested in a solution to my original question though.